# Saving Image on glassfish using a webservice

Tags: java, glassfish

I am currently writing a web service that stores an image on a directory on my glassfish server instance. For some reason, when the web service is consumed from the client, it says that directory or the file is not found. I am passing a byte array to the method. Below is my code:

```
@WebMethod(operationName="upload")
public String upload(String fileName, byte[] imageBytes){
    String filePath = "/bucketlister/images/feature pictures/"+fileName;
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bos.write(imageBytes);
        bos.close();
        return "Received file:" + filePath;
    }catch(IOException e){
        throw new WebServiceException(e);
    }
}
```

the FileOutputStream throws a FileNotFoundException. Any ideas? I would prefer to use a byte array, but I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: Did you check the docs? Specifically, > [*FileNotFoundException - if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) More detail to the exception or problem would help

Comment: @NickBell it says No such File or Directory

Comment: You've got a space in your `filePath`

Comment: Also, is that a relative path or an absolute path? If it should be relative, it's being interpreted as absolute.

Comment: @Mike so how can I help that? I would like it to be interpreted as relative

Comment: You started your path with a forward slash `/` so the path is read as though `bucketlister` is in the root directory. If you want a relative path, then I believe GlassFish reads from the `glassfish/domains/${your_domain}/config/` directory, so you could move `bucketlister` there and remove the forward slash from the beginning. Also make sure that there are no spaces in the path.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer was staring at me all the while..  The filePath was pointing to only half the directory. It should have gone

```
    String filePath ="home/user/glassfish4/domains/domain1/bucketlister/images/feature_picture/" + fileName;
```

I don't know if it changes anything, but I changed the "feature picture" directory to "feature_picture"